# Infinite number of process spawns despite wait and kill (bash)

Tags: bash, daemon, nc

This code should be a daemon that keeps alive `nc` command. If `nc` instance is dead then the daemon should *respawn* it.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" != "__forked__" ]; then
    setsid "$0" __forked__ "$@" &
    exit
else
    shift
fi

trap 'echo "Clean up and exit"; kill $nc_pid; exit' TERM
exec > outfile
exec 2> errfile
exec 0< /dev/null

while true; do
    (nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash &>/dev/null) &
    nc_pid=$!
    wait $nc_pid
    kill $nc_pid &>/dev/null
done
```

When I execute this code it keeps spawning a new `nc` instance without killing the previous one.

```
logan      14443  0.0  0.0   2588  1860 ?        S    18:45   0:00 nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash
logan      14446  0.0  0.0   2588  1844 ?        S    18:45   0:00 nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash
logan      14449  0.0  0.0   2588  1900 ?        S    18:45   0:00 nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash
logan      14452  0.0  0.0   2588  1888 ?        S    18:45   0:00 nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash
logan      14455  0.0  0.0   2588  1880 ?        S    18:45   0:00 nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash
logan      14458  0.0  0.0   2588  1944 ?        S    18:45   0:00 nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash
logan      14461  0.0  0.0   2588  1880 ?        S    18:45   0:00 nc -lkp 1234 -e /usr/bin/bash
...
```

I want only **one** instance of `nc` at any time. How to fix this code?

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine, but: What is a logic behind using `kill` after `wait`? Process should be clearly dead by then. Why even bother using wait and executing nc in background as you can do it in loop without background running and it should be running one command at time (if nc dies loop will run another instance)? Also if you really really want to find out what's wrong I would start with debugging return values from `wait` commands.

Comment: @DevilaN have you tried `ps aux | grep ' [n]c' to list nc processes? for me it gives me a long growing list (like above).

Comment: @DevilaN also nc is forked.

Comment: One process only at time. No change in pid unless I kill process by hand. Please add debug info echoing `$nc_pid` and return status from wait in each loop iteration

Comment: @DevilaN thanks for you help. because shebang is set to /bin/sh that's why this behavior. setting she-bang to bash made i work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work in `/bin/sh`, switch to `/bin/bash` and it should.